# Text file to dictionary with formatting the text

Tags: python

I'm struggling to  create the dictionary out of txt file which contains following:

```
20
Robert  Jack                   
Robert  Gary
Lizzie  Dave
Lena
Mia     Dave
Mia     Caroline
Rafael
Robert  Nick
Daniela Jack
Danny   Merry
Danny   Joel
Adam    Robert
Adam    Mia
Chris   Mario
Chris   June
Chris   Joel
Joel    Benny
Wayne   Jack
```

Social network showing list of people and their friends, I have to change the data into dictionary and present people with their friends next to them as follows: Robert -> Gary, Jack  etc.

```
with open('nw_data1.txt', 'r') as f: 
    lines = f.readlines() 
            file_dict = {} 


    for line in lines: 

        key, value = line.split('-', '>') 
        key = key.strip() 
        value = value.strip() 
        file_dict[key] = value 

        print(file_dict)
```

Comment: And? Is there a problem with your code? What is your question? The first step to being able to fix your code is being able to describe what is wrong with it. Please see [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: These will also be helpful: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
and
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: Ok it was just a question I'm not experienced, no need to be rude thank you for effort.

Comment: I'm sorry for any perceived rudeness, I didn't mean to be rude. The comment has nothing to do with your experience. When you ask a question on Stack Overflow, you need to actually _ask a question!_. All I did was point you to some resources that would help you improve your question.

Comment: I will try to improve thank you for advices, all of that is just overwhelming sometimes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `collections.defaultdict` to solve this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('nw_data1.txt', 'r') as f: 
    lines = f.readlines() 

network = defaultdict(list)

for line in lines:
    name, *friends = line.split()
    network[name] += friends
```

With `network` now being:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
  'Robert': ['Jack', 'Gary', 'Nick'], 
  'Lizzie': ['Dave'], 
  'Lena': [],   
  'Mia': ['Dave', 'Caroline'], 
  'Rafael': [], 
  'Daniela': ['Jack'], 
  'Danny': ['Merry', 'Joel'], 
  'Adam': ['Robert', 'Mia'], 
  'Chris': ['Mario', 'June', 'Joel'], 
  'Joel': ['Benny'], 
  'Wayne': ['Jack']
})
```

Comment: every coding I tired always comes back with the same  error                                                               name, * friends = line.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0)

Comment: That suggests you have an empty line in your file somewhere.

Comment: Chris thank you I didn't know single empty line can create such a problem ..... most of the code I wrote was working perfectly fine it was just that one empty line you are my hero thank you :)